# Enqueueing styles with version variable

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

My version variable doesn't seem to be being applied within my enqueue functions (snippet below).

```
//version number
$version = '1.0.0';

function frontend_styles($version) {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'frontend_styles', //reference
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/app.min.css', //source
        array(), //dependenices
        $version, //version number
        'all' //media type ('all', 'screen', 'handheld', 'print')
    );
}
```

Is there a way of setting a global version number that could be applied to all styles?

EDIT:
Below is the actual source code.

```
//version number
$version = '1.0.0';

//remove jquery scripts
function remove_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-core');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate');
}

//remove embed scripts
function remove_embed() {
    wp_deregister_script('wp-embed');
}

//site styles
function frontend_styles() {
    global $version;
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'frontend_styles', //reference
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/app.min.css', //source
        array(), //dependenices
        $version, //version number
        'all' //media type ('all', 'screen', 'handheld', 'print')
    );
}

//admin_styles
function backend_styles() {
    global $version;
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'backend_styles', //reference
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin.min.css', //source
        array(), //dependenices
        $version, //version number
        'all' //media type ('all', 'screen', 'handheld', 'print')
    );
}

//site scripts
function frontend_scripts() {
    global $version;
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'frontend_scripts', //reference
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/app.min.js', //source
        array(), //dependencies
        $version, //version number
        true //load in footer
    );

    //pass sylsheet uri to javascript variable in app.js
    $translation_array = array(
        'get_stylesheet_directory_uri'  => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/',
        'home_url'                      => home_url('/')
    );

    wp_localize_script('frontend_scripts', 'php', $translation_array);
}

//admin scripts
function backend_scripts() {
    global $version;
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'backend_scripts', //reference
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/admin.min.js', //source
        array(), //dependencies
        $version, //version number
        true //load in footer
    );
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not used? Are you sure it is not another plugin removing the version numbers?

Comment: It doesn't appear at all? So, not appended to the url of your CSS? or does another version appear?

Comment: It seems that wordpress is reverting to it's default version number. The same way it would if $version was defined as null

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// global theme version
$version = '1.0.0';

function frontend_styles() {

   global $version;
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'frontend_styles', //reference
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/app.min.css', //source
        array(), //dependenices
        $version, //version number
        'all' //media type ('all', 'screen', 'handheld', 'print')
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello @florian. In my snippet, WP appends the stylesheet url with "?ver=4.9.7" (the version of WP I've installed). By amending my code with what you suggested it seems to have removed all versioning altogether.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Can you check if the version variabele is set within the function and after calling the global $version.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not defined within the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the `frontend_styles()` function.

If you define `$version` outside a function, in the *global* scope, you need to use the `global` keyword inside the function to access it:

```
//version number
$version = '1.0.0';

function frontend_styles() {
    global $version;

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'frontend_styles', //reference
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/app.min.css', //source
        array(), //dependenices
        $version, //version number
        'all' //media type ('all', 'screen', 'handheld', 'print')
    );
}
```

Comment: @Florian Sorry, rejected your edit initially because I got the before and after mixed up. Have since made the same fix.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've just replied to Florian, but I'll paste the comment below for easy viewing:

In my snippet, WP appends the stylesheet url with "?ver=4.9.7" (the version of WP I've installed). By amending my code with what you suggested it seems to have removed all versioning altogether.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Is `$version` defined the same way and in the same place in your actual code?

Comment: ```
Source code:

     //version number
 $version = '1.0.0';

 //remove embed scripts
 function remove_embed() {
  wp_deregister_script('wp-embed');
 }

 //site styles
 function frontend_styles($version) {
  wp_enqueue_style(
   'frontend_styles', //reference
   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/app.min.css', //source
   array(), //dependenices
   $version, //version number
   'all' //media type ('all', 'screen', 'handheld', 'print')
  );
 }
```

Comment: Could you add that to the question so that it can be formatted to be more readable?

Comment: No problem. It has now been edited

Comment: Is that the version that includes the suggestion Florian and I made? I don't see the `global` keyword anywhere. Also, the functions shouldn't have `$version` in the parameters.

Comment: It does not. It's the raw source code.

Comment: Well you should update the source code to incorporate our suggestion. I can't debug the reason the suggestion might not be working by looking at code that does not incorporate the suggestion.

Comment: No problem.
I've updated the source code section in the original question to incorporate the proposed solution.

Comment: I tested your amended code and it works fine. The correct version number is showing. Are you looking at the correct URLs? I notice that your code isn't actually hooking the functions anywhere. Does your actual code properly hook these functions?

Comment: Yes, I have the hooks in a separate file.
I appreciate the time you've put in to helping me, and don't wish to inconvenience you any further. I'll keep looking at it and see if I can troubleshoot where the issue lies. Thanks!